Can you give me an example of an implicit use of Godel's Completeness Theorem, say for example in group theory?
Wikipedia says that the more general form of Godel's completeness is "used implicitly, for example, when a sentence is shown to be provable from the axioms of group theory by considering an arbitrary group and showing that the sentence is satisfied by that group."
How so? Can you give me an example?
EDIT: In his answer, Qiaochu Yuan proposed the following example:

Proposition: conjugate elements have the same order.

Just for fun, I challenged myself to prove this without explicitly going from the axioms: seeing the elements as permutations, we know the proposition is true because conjugate permutations share the same cycle type (and therefore, the same order); apply Cayley's Theorem and we are done.
In this proof I did not reason from the axioms, but there is obviously (implicitly) a set of deductions from the axioms underlying it. Is this what Wikipedia is trying to say?

Sure, sometimes, you can find a purely semantical proof of a statement (and I think you can probably even formally show that this is true for a very large class of statements, although probably not "all", depending on your metatheory). But I doubt you would argue that it is more natural than arguing from the axioms (explicitly or implicitly).

Generally, this sort of thing is going to be much more difficult, since most elementary classes of first order structures don't have such "concrete" representability theorems as Cayley's theorem.

Thank you for the comments! Can you give me an example of a purely semantical proof in group theory? Is the one I mentioned in my edit "purely semantical"?

I did not have any rigorous meaning in mind (and I doubt there is any one which would be interesting, rigorous and without caveats). But yes, this is the kind of argument I was referring to.

By the way, a typical way we obtain these sorts of results is in algebraically closed and real closed fields, where you can use topological properties of complex and real numbers to prove their first-order properties, which then apply to all algebraically closed fields of characteristic 0 (and algebraically closed fields of all but finitely many positive characteristics) and all real closed fields.

A simple example might be something like the following:

Proposition: An element $g \in G$ of a group and any of its conjugates $hgh^{-1} \in G$ have the same order.

This is a collection of first-order statements in the language of group theory indexed by a positive integer $n$ of the form: for all $g, h \in G$, if $g^n = e$ and $g^d \neq e$ for any $1 < 
d < n$, then the same is true of $hgh^{-1}$. (As far as I know the statement "$g$ has infinite order" is not first-order so technically we have to exclude this case.) So the completeness theorem tells you that each of these statements is provable from the first-order axioms of group theory iff they're true in every group.
But this doesn't actually buy you anything, because the proof you'd use to show these statements are true in every group is... just to prove them from the first-order axioms of group theory.
I know one interesting example where the completeness theorem actually tells you something nontrivial in algebra, but it's in ring theory rather than group theory: Jacobson's theorem says that if a ring $R$ has the property that there exists a positive integer $n$ such that $r^n = r$ for all $r \in R$, then $R$ is commutative. The proof of Jacobson's theorem is not a proof from the first-order axioms of ring theory; actually first-order reasoning about rings is quite restrictive and can't even discuss ideals, and the proof of Jacobson's theorem involves quotienting by ideals and several other ideas besides.
However, because the statement of Jacobson's theorem (for fixed $n$) is first-order, the completeness theorem implies that there must, for every positive integer $n$, exist a proof of Jacobson's theorem for $n$ from the first-order axioms of ring theory. As far as I know these proofs have not yet been written down explicitly for all $n$, although see Brandenburg's Equational proofs of Jacobson's theorem for many special cases.

"But this doesn't actually buy you anything, because the proof you'd use to show these statements are true in every group is... just to prove them from the first-order axioms of group theory." That was what I thought it all examples I came up with!

Your ring theory example is awesome, thank you!

Re ‘As far as I know the statement " has infinite order" is not first-order’: Indeed, it’s not first-order, by a standard compactness argument.  Suppose we have a formula $\eta(x)$ representing “$x$ has infinite order”.  Consider the theory with axioms ${ a^n \neq 0 \mid n \in \mathbb{N} }$ together with $\lnot \eta(a)$, for a new constant $a$.  Each finite subtheory can be modelled by taking $a$ to have sufficiently large order; but in any model of the whole theory, $a$ should have finite order (by the axiom $\lnot \eta(a)$), but can’t have any specific finite order.  Contradiction.

Interesting example. Can't we construct a two-sorted first order theory with a sort for the natural numbers and a sort for the elements of a group in which we can state Jacobson's theorem in full generality? So the completeness theorem (which works in a two-sorted setting) would tell us that there is a first-order proof of Jacobson's theorem. Or am I missing something.

@Rob: that would follow if we knew that Jacobson’s theorem was true for all models of this two-sorted theory, including models where the naturals are nonstandard, which seems to me to make things complicated.

@RobArthan: The problem is that this sort of statement will be an arithmetical fact, not just group-theoretic (you're basically asking to add a second sort for arithmetic). I'm pretty sure you can do the same sort of thing with e.g. the axiom schemas of ZFC. As Qiaochu says, this will give you nonstandard finite orders (as in the ZFC case you would have nonstandard $L_{\mathrm{set}}$-formulas). This is not really an obstacle to formulating it this way, but I don't really see how this would be useful, only more complex.

@QiaochuYuan: I don't think this is really a problem. More precisely, for the correct theory, this statement will be true in any nonstandard model (because Jacobson's theorem will of course have to be a theorem). This means that you would have groups of pseudofinite exponent which will be abelian by Jacobson's theorem, sure. That may be a bit funny, but there is no contradiction. There are infinite exponent abelian groups after all.

@tomasz: I don't understand the impact of your very interesting comments. To be more specific: will $\forall n^N > 1((\forall r^R(r^n = r)) \Rightarrow (\forall r^R s^R(rs = sr)))$ be true in the two-sorted theory? And if so, will it be provable?

@RobArthan: Yes, it will be true, because this is true for groups (assuming that your two-sorted theory is actually the two-sorted theory of groups with order function). Yes, it will be provable - by the completeness theorem. (Or trivially, depending on how you axiomatise the theory.) Of course, if you actually put there the full arithmetic, then the theory will not be recursively axiomatisable, by the other famous theorem of Godel.

It's worth noting that we rarely care about the existence of a first-order proof from a given set of axioms. A first-order proof is a very messy object, and if we're not already interested in them for their own sake (e.g. when studying proof theory) they don't usually add much to the subject we're focusing on.
Completeness theorems for weaker logics can be more useful, because the corresponding proof notions are tamer and so more easily mined for consequences. Here's a nice example from Burris/Sankappanavar: Theorem 14.19 shows that whenever $\mathcal{E}$ is an equational theory and $\eta$ is an equation which is true in every model of $\mathcal{E}$, then there is an equational derivation of $\eta$ from $\mathcal{E}$. Due to the very limited form of equational derivations, it's easy to prove that no equational derivation can introduce "unbalancing:" if each hypothesis in a given equational derivation contains the same number of occurrences of each variable on both sides of the $\approx$-sign, then the conclusion must also have this property. So any time we have a variety axiomatized by balanced equations, every unbalanced equation must fail somewhere in that variety. (This is the content of Example 1 following the theorem above.)
Analogous arguments for first-order proofs are much rarer since these, being more complicated, only admit much more subtle preservation properties. The arguments which do exist tend to have two steps: first show that every deduction in a restricted calculus preserves a certain property, and then show that - at least in the case of interest - every first-order proof can be replaced by one in that restricted calculus. This is the idea behind a Gentzen-style consistency proof, for example: first (generally easy) show that there is no cut-free proof of $\perp$ from the theory in question, and then (generally extremely hard) show that we can in fact eliminate cuts from our proofs. Note, though, that this has nothing to do with the completeness theorem; it's just an example of the extreme complexity of the combinatorial analysis of first-order proofs.

While I agree that in mathematical practice, knowing that there is a first-order proof (and not only that the result is true) is usually not very important. However, in my opinion, the completeness theorem is philosophically still quite meaningful in many situations where we have a proof which is far from first-order and a first-order proof seems far off. I think if we didn't have the completeness theorem, then many such claims would be much more suspect. In other words, I think the reason why we do not care so much is because we already know it's true.

I think it can also serve as a motivation for new (first order) proof strategies, although I confess I have no examples like that in mind.
